# Can a signed mobile application be altered?

Tags: mobile, digital-signature, integrity, software

If a signed mobile application is modified, then its signature and checksum become invalid.

Is it *possible* to forge a new, valid signature?

Comment: No proabably not.

Comment: Why?please give reasons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, yes, it is possible to make an arbitrary application and pad it such that the hash matches, but in reality, this is extremely difficult to impossible unless the hash used has known weaknesses.

A good hash works because it has a large number of possible outputs and it is difficult to predict the output from the input.  As long as the hash succeeds at these two criteria, an attacker would need to brute force a crack by making changes to their program until they can get a hash collision.  Since the collision space is so large on modern secure hashes, it would take impractically long times (centuries or longer) to generate a hash collision even while spending government levels of computing on generating a collision.

The odds for the attacker improve a little if they are trying to produce a "good version" and a "bad version" that match intentionally as they can "meet in the middle" by making a bunch of different good builds and a bunch of different bad ones and just need any two of them to match, but it's still highly impractical due to the amount of computation required to even manage that with secure modern cryptographic hashes.

Comment: Is this hash used in making the app the same as the hash used in the ssl certificate of the apps developer

Comment: No, the hash would need to be the same as the hash of the unmodified application, so that it could be verified using a certificate.

Comment: It's similar in principle, but not the same hash.  Both an SSL cert and an application can be signed to prove their authenticity.  A signature works by encrypting a hash with a private key such that a known public key can be used to decrypt it.  To verify the signature, the program checking the validity runs a new hash of the signed item and compares it to the value decrypted with the public key.  If they match, the signature is valid and trusted since only the holder of the private key could have encrypted the signature hash.

Comment: It's much harder to falsify a cert as a cert holds to a pretty fixed format, however an executable can contain pretty arbitrary and long contents, so it's much easier to pad.  Determining padding for a collision is still extremely hard, but there's at least a way to place the padding in an executable.

Comment: So if i know which hash is used in the ssl certificate is it compulasory that the same hash is used to sign the app. And if it is not compulsory is it common?

Comment: @bangbam SSL signing and app signing aren't inter-related.  You do not even need an SSL cert to do application signing.  Application signing verifies the hash of the application against a known good public key.  SSL signing verifies a public key (certificate) against another known good public key.  It is possible that an application can use a digital certificate as the public key to verify the software publisher is who they say they are, such as kernel mode signing for Windows, but that's just using the two applications of the technology in parallel.  The hashes don't have to be the same.

Comment: Sha 1 is now a weak hash so using it means that a signature can be forged and hence insecure?

Answer (score 0):

There may be several ways to modify the code *without* changing the signature:

- **Exploiting an implementation vulnerability** - The [Android Master Key vulnarability](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/08/09/android-master-key-vulnerability-more-malware-found-exploiting-code-verification-bypass/) is an example of exactly one such issue, which allowed malicious users to add executable code to a signed APK without changing the signature.
- **Exposing a hash collision** - Signatures based on hash functions depend on the security of the hash.  SHA-1, for example, was [recently broken](http://thehackernews.com/2017/02/sha1-collision-attack.html) by Google; in that case, two pdf files with the same hash were produced.  Extending such an attack, it may be possible to produce a different application with the same signature as the correct one.